# Webforms custom validator doesn't work inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms, updatepanel

There is a form below. The *startDateValidator* is outside of update panel and works fine. The *UsersRequiredValidator* is inside of update panel and doesn't work. Custom validation methods are completely ignored. In the update panel I can do some operations with postbacks (add/remove users to/from listbox). How I can get my custom validator working as another validators outside of update panel.

```
<div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStartDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="startDateValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate" ErrorMessage="Start Date is required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btAddUser" runat="server" Text="Add User" OnClick="btAddUser_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btRemoveUser" runat="server" Text="Remove User" OnClick="btRemoveUser_Click" />
        <asp:ListBox ID="lbUsers" runat="server"/>
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="UsersRequiredValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="lbUsers" ErrorMessage="You must add at least one user" OnServerValidate="CustomReruqiredUsersValidator_ServerValidate" ClientValidationFunction="onRequiredUsersValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: If your `CustomValidator` is working without update panel then try adding a `PageRequestManager` inside javascript. Here the link [PageRequestManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311028(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal, the main problem was with `lbUsers`. When I added or removed users from list box validator didn't work. I realized that validator starts to work if you click on list box and select any option. So I used your advice and added the js line which simulates clicking on list box. I've added it to `add_endRequest` method of `PageRequestManager`. I don't like this solution, but it is only one working for me. Thanks.